# FIrestore document onUpdate: trigger only for specific fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

in my cloud function I have next unction:

```js
export const collectionOnUpdate = functions.firestore.document('cards/{id}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
  await updateDocumentInAlgolia(change);
});
```

And this function is triggered each time, when any fields of document was edited. But I want to run it only when one of specific fields was changed (in this case, for example: `title`, `category`) and not when any of other.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

firebase firstore `cloud functions` are works based on the basis of changes to the  documents,not based on the fields of a document.

So if you want to check whether some fields have any change,you have to check manually

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {

  // ...the new value after this update
  const newValue = change.after.data()||{};

  // ...the previous value before this update
  const previousValue = change.before.data()||{};

  // access a particular field as you would any JS property

  //The value after an update operation
  const new_name = newValue.name;

  // the value before an update operation
  const old_name = previousValue.name;

  if(new_name!==old_name){
   //There must be some changes
   // perform desired operations ...
  }else{
  //No changes to the field called `name`
  // perform desired operations ...
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#specifying_the_document_path), functions only respond to document changes, and cannot monitor specific fields or collections.